# Is there a programmatic way to check if your function is being called synchronous or asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Is there a way to tell if your function is being called synchronously or asynchronously?

For example, if I have a function shown below?

```
async function callMe() {
     console.log("Am I called asynchronously?", callMe.isCalledAsync);
}

callMe(); // false
await callMe(); // true
```

The use case is I've needed to convert an existing function from `sync` to `async` and for testing purposes and because Chrome Debugger is reporting odd results, I want to check from inside the function that it's being called asynchronously. Another use case is if it's a public method than I want to make sure it's called using `await`.

Chrome Debugger seems to be aware of the `await` and `async` as shown in the screenshot below but either the debugger is incorrect or my code is incorrect or the JIT is not processing the calls async because Chrome Debugger is saying that only the first call is async but the recursive calls are not as shown in the image below.

[image]

[image]

---

We all know what you are supposed to do. But developers don't always do that; on purpose or on accident. And that's where dev tools like type checkers and autocomplete and intellisense and all development tools help assist and remind developers what's going on and what we might have missed. So having the feature doesn't preclude or prevent writing good code.

Comment: Sounds like an anti pattern waiting to happen - what’s your use case? Async is just syntactic sugar for “this function returns a promise”, the function shouldn’t care whether the caller ignores the promise or not

Comment: @Clive I've updated the use case

Comment: No you can’t do that, for the reason mentioned in the first comment. Don’t forget a valid, identical alternative to using `await` is to invoke `.then()` on the returned promise. So the function will never know what the caller did or didn’t do with the promise (unless you introduce a mechanism to do that, but it would be awkward and wouldn’t make much sense to do so)

Comment: There is no such thing as "called asynchronously" or "called synchronously"..  Your function is just called.  It's up to the caller whether they choose to use a promise you return or not and what they do with that promise.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible for a function to determine if a caller used the `await` keyword. It's not even possible for a function to have knowledge from the runtime about whether or not a caller invoked it in an async context.

> Because it's a public method I want to make sure it's called using await.

This is the responsibility of a compile-time lint rule, not of a function's runtime implementation. You (or the linter) will need to examine the source/AST of the calling code to make that determination.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might make a nice es2023 feature. The JS interpreter should have information on what is and what isn't being called asynchronously. Hopefully for my sake, they can provide that information if needed.

Comment: I've updated the post with more information. It seems Chrome Debugger is aware of await and async calls and either there's an error with the Chrome Debugger or there's something else going on.